# ko.applyBinding to refresh the search results using Knockout?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I want to update the contents of my databind Ul-Li list with the searched data. I am using following ViewModel

```
function PatientsModel(data)
{
    var self = this;

    self.Patients = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Patients(data.Patients);

    self.addPatient = function (model, event)
    {
        alert("Patients to Add: " + model.LastName + ',' + model.FirstName);
        //Replace with AJAX Calls : self.people.push({ name: "New at " + new Date() });
    };

    self.removePatient = function (model, event)
    {
        alert("Patients to Delete:" + model.LastName + ',' + model.FirstName);
        //Replace with AJAX calls : self.people.remove(this);
    }

    self.RefreshData = function (data)
    {
        self.Patients = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.Patients(data.Patients);
    }
}
```

to refresh the contents I have created RefreshData, method that will update **Patients** which is data-bind  **"foreach: Patients"** with Ul

I am doing following Bind:

```
AllPatientList.PatientsModel = null;
                            AllPatientList.PatientsModel = new PatientsModel(data);
                            ko.applyBindings(AllPatientList.PatientsModel, $('#AllPatientDiv>div>ul')[0]);
```

and Following to Update the contents of View Model:

```
if (AllPatientList.PatientsModel != null && AllPatientList.PatientsModel != undefined)
                            {
                                AllPatientList.PatientsModel.RefreshData(data);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                AllPatientList.PatientsModel = new PatientsModel(data);
                                ko.applyBindings(AllPatientList.PatientsModel, $('#AllPatientDiv>div>ul')[0]);
                        }
```

But it Doesn't work and contents of the UL are **not changing**.

Further I tried to do Following:

```
ko.cleanNode($('#AllPatientDiv>div>ul')[0]);
AllPatientList.PatientsModel = new PatientsModel(data);
                                ko.applyBindings(AllPatientList.PatientsModel, $('#AllPatientDiv>div>ul')[0]);
```

It is producing the list with Repeated/Duplicate dataEntries. It is showing 9 list-items instead of 3. (Each repeating 3 times).

I am not able to figure out what's wrong I have done here. ko.cleanNode() is not removing contents from the list as well. Please Help, how can I rebind the UL - LI list with updated Contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't changing because your RefreshData function is breaking the binding. When you first call `applyBindings()` a subscription to the `Patients` array is created. When you call `RefreshData` you are **overwriting** the array with a new one. This new array has no binding subscriptions.

If you want to clear the old array, use `removeAll` before adding the new data. This will keep the binding subscription intact.

Edit:

Here is a [very simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n4fj/) demonstrating this

Comment: Stackoverflow holding me to select Answer :)

Comment: It was happening because your response worked straight away, and I tried to chose it as answer. But, there is a particular time frame after submitting the question and only after what I can chose one response as ANswer. Thanks Tyrsius

Comment: Oh, yea that thing. Got it now =)

Comment: I don't know why but somehow, it stopped working. removeAll is removing the li elements in the HTML. Any guess why?